# How to use QSortFilterProxyModel to filter a tree model, and show the entire node if searched?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a `TreeView/TreeModel` project. The `TreeModel` is derived from `QAbstractItemModel` and I'm trying to implement a filter to search text in the whole `TreeView`. To do this I'm using the `QSortFilterProxyModel` class.

At this time the default behavior of the filter is as follows:

If any text is searched for and if the text is found within a child or subchild of a TreeNode, the TreeNode hierarchy will be returned but only with the matching data.

For example:
If I search `test` in a Tree like this:

```
A0 
  A1
  B1
  C1
  D1
    test
A2 
  A2
  B2
  C2
  D2
    D2 child
```

The result will be:

```
A0 
  D1
    test
```

This is the most common behavior of a search filter and I want to keep it.

But If I search `A0` in a Tree like this:

```
A0 
  A1
  B1
  C1
  D1
    test
A2 
  A2
  B2
  C2
  D2
    D2 child
```

The result will be:

```
A0
```

I would like to add a condition to show the entire tree if a node is searched. For example:

If I search `A0` in the following Tree

```
A0 
  A1
  B1
  C1
  D1
    test 
A2 
  A2
  B2
  C2
  D2
    D2 child
```

I would like to see the following output:

```
A0 
  A1
  B1
  C1
  D1
    test
```

Also If I search `D1` in the following tree

```
A0 
  A1
  B1
  C1
  D1
    test 1
    test 2
    test 3
A2 
  A2
  B2
  C2
  D2
    D2 child
```

I would like to see the following output:

```
A0 
  D1
    test 1
    test 2
    test 3
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    TreeModel *model = new TreeModel(file.readAll());
    file.close();

    lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
    connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &MainWindow::searchItem);

    proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxyModel->setFilterKeyColumn(0);
    proxyModel->setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(true);
    proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);

    treeView = new QTreeView(this);
    treeView->setModel(proxyModel);
    treeView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    treeView->expandAll();
}

void MainWindow::searchItem() {
    proxyModel->setFilterRegExp(lineEdit->text());
}
```

I think the behavior could be overridden, but I don't know where or how to do it, any suggestions?

Btw I'm using the SimpleTreeModel example provided by QT to generate the TreeModel:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your code, you seem to be using some version of Qt5 (contrary to the link you have posted which was for Qt6).

Sadly, the way to do what you ask has only been added to `QSortFilterProxyModel` in Qt6.0. You would have to call:

```
proxyModel->setAutoAcceptChildRows(true);
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#autoAcceptChildRows-prop).

I strongly recommend you move away from Qt5, which goes out of support (except for subscribers) in May 2023, and move to Qt6.

Comment: You are right, I am using QT5. I work on a QT project using a subscription. Unfortunately, it is not possible for me to switch to QT6. So there is no other alternative to modify the behavior of the filter?. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You could subclass the proxy model to reimplement `filterAcceptsRow` so that if an index is filtered out by `QSortFilterProxyModel`, you peek at his parent (and grand parent and so on).

Comment: BTW, the reason why I knew you were on Qt5 was because you use `setFilterRegExp`. `QRegExp` and in general everything containing *regexp* in their name has disappeared in Qt6. Use `setFilterRegularExpression` and `QRegularExpression` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot Atmo. I'll use `setFilterRegularExpression` instead.